# How to populate data into Multiple UIPickerView?

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I have two fields that call UIPickerView (Country and Province). I'm using inputView to show the picker view. Both using one picker view but how do I populate based on the field?

**Here I put sample code**

This code get executed after picker view events! Someone suggest me to put this code in wright place.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField;
{
// Check if the field is Country
if (textField.tag == 3) {
    pickerData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [pickerData addObject:@"Australia"];
    [pickerData addObject:@"Canada"];
    [pickerData addObject:@"India"];
    [pickerData addObject:@"China"];
    [pickerData addObject:@"United States"];
    [pickerData addObject:@"United Kingdom"];
    [pickerData addObject:@"New Zealand"];

    txtCountry.inputView = picker;
    picker.hidden = NO;
}

// Check if the field is Province
else if (textField.tag == 4) {
    if ([[txtCountry text] isEqualToString: @"Canada"]) {
        pickerData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [pickerData addObject:@"Quebec"];
        [pickerData addObject:@"Ontario"];
        [pickerData addObject:@"British Columbia"];
        [pickerData addObject:@"Prince Evard Island"];
        [pickerData addObject:@"Alberta"];
        [pickerData addObject:@"Sascatchwan"];

        txtProvince.inputView = picker;
        picker.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {
        txtProvince.inputView = nil;
        picker.hidden = YES;
    }
}
else {
    picker.hidden = YES;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set it's datasource to pickerData?

You can call method [yourPickerData reloadAllComponents];

Comment: You are welcome. My advice for documentation viewer would be ingredients, it's missing documentation viewer for XCode 4.x